# Android: Sending Command Over Internet to Service and Taking a Picture

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-service

I've augmented this camera code and I am able to take a picture without a problem: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-essentials-create-a-mirror/

I've created a bounded service that receives a command over the internet and launches a runnable thread, which then takes a picture. I have zero problems with the bounded service and launching the runnable thread. When my phone sends a command to a server and receives the command back through the service, I can take a picture without a problem. However, if an external device sends a command, the runnable thread runs, but then crashes at mCamera.takePicture() with a null pointer exception.

```
public class RunnableEventA implements Runnable {

    private Camera mCamera;
    private MirrorActivity mActivity;



    public RunnableEventA(Camera camera, Activity activity) {
        mCamera = camera;
        mActivity = (MirrorActivity) activity;
    } 

    public void run() {
        Log.d("sent", "Runnable here");
        //mCamera.takePicture(null, null, this);
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mActivity);
    }

}
```

The Activity and mCamera are passed to the runnable thread through the bounded service passed in MirrorActivity in the onConnected method:

```
/** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                IBinder service) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();

            mBound = true;

            /* Send parameters to Service*/
            mService.setParams(MirrorActivity.this, mCamera);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong or need to add? I don't want to bloat this post with code, so if you think you need to see anything additional, let me know.

Comment: Apparently the Activity and camera are null. Any thoughts on why this might be the case, even though the parameters are passed in the onServiceConnected method?

Comment: Problem solved! The Activity and camera were being passed to the service correctly, but were not being passed correctly to the runnable thread.